# Call to EventHandler in ASCX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

I am updating an ASCX page and I saw an EventHandler defined then later called.
`public event EventHandler Step1Submit;`
Then later on in the code
`Step1Submit(sender, e);`

In the ASPX page, there is the tag

```
<uc3:SignUpStep1Control ID="signUpStep1" runat="server" 
                        OnStep1Submit="SignUpStep1_Click" />
```

My question is, when `Step1Submit(sender, e);` is executed, is it calling `SignUpStep1_Click()` event in the ASPX code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're "deferring" event handling for event "OnStep1Submit" to function SignUpStep1_Click. So yes SignUpStep1_Click will be executed, and you need to have it defined in your aspx.cs file in order to compile. Same thing as a click event on a button or any other event actually.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that is what was happening.